# Database syncing playback of videos

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html5

I made a website last night that allows people to sync HTML5 `<video>`s (playing/pausing). The way it does this is by using Ajax to run a MySQL query every 2 seconds to check if anyone has paused the video. Depending on the response, it plays/pauses it. If someone plays/pauses the video, it calls a page through Ajax to update the database.

This is the page that plays the video and manages the syncing:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        require('/connect/streaming.php'); //On this page: $con = mysqli_connect(host, user, pass, database)
        $query = "SELECT link FROM vids WHERE vidKey = ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
        $stmt->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultFirst = $stmt->get_result();
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultFirst);
    ?>
        <video controls autoplay name="media" id="vid">
            <source src="<?php echo $result['link']; ?>" type="video/<?php echo $_GET['type']; ?>">
        </video><br>
        <a onclick="flipCheck()" id="checkA">Click here to disable checks</a>
        <script>
            var checking = true;
            function flipCheck() {
                if (checking) {
                    checking = false;
                    $("#checkA").html("Click here to enable checks");
                }
                else {
                    checking = true;
                    $("#checkA").html("Click here to disable checks");
                }
            }
            //Pause video on load
            $(document).ready(function() {
              var vid = document.getElementById("vid"); 
              vid.pause();
            });

            //Every second, check what others are doing
            window.setInterval(function(){
              request({'type': 'get', 'vidId': <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?> });
            }, 2000);

            //On play, tell the server
            vid.onplaying = function() {
                request({'type': 'update', 'vidId': <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>, 'timestamp': vid.currentTime, 'status': 'playing' });
            };

            //On pause, tell the server
            vid.onpause = function() {
                request({'type': 'update', 'vidId': <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>, 'timestamp': vid.currentTime, 'status': 'paused' });
            };

            //Function to request data
            function request(funcData) {
                if (checking) {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "https://chipperyman.com/streaming/process.php", 
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: funcData,
                        success: function(result){
                            console.log(result);
                            if (result['msg'] == 'paused') {
                                vid.pause();
                                vid.currentTime = result['timestamp'];
                            }
                            else if (result['msg'] == 'playing') {
                                if (vid.paused) {
                                    vid.currentTime = result['timestamp'];
                                    vid.play();
                                }
                            }
                    }}); 
                }
            }
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the page that manages the Ajax calls:

```
<?php
//MySQL
require('/connect/streaming.php'); //On this page: $con = mysqli_connect(host, user, pass, database)
//Setup checkArgs
function checkArgs(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg){
        if (!isset($_GET[$arg])) {
            die(json_encode(array('response' => 'error', "msg" => "Missing args")));
        }
    }
}

//Check for type and vidId
checkArgs('type', 'vidId');
//If we're updating 
if ($_GET['type'] == 'update') {
    checkArgs('timestamp', 'status');
    $query = "UPDATE vids SET timestamp = ?, status = ? WHERE vidKey = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('dsi', $_GET['timestamp'], $_GET['status'], $_GET['vidId']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $response = array("response" => "success", "msg" => "Preformed action.");
}
else if ($_GET['type'] == 'get') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM vids WHERE vidKey = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['vidId']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultFirst = $stmt->get_result();
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultFirst);
    $response = array("response" => "success", "msg" => $result['status'], "timestamp" => $result['timestamp']);
}
else {
    $response = array("response" => "error", "msg" => "Invalid type argument");
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

This is the database layout:

[image: MySQL Database Layout]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with the HTML5 `video` tag, so I will not say anything about that.

Your code is open to reflected XSS here: `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>` (inside script tags).

You might also think about extracting some code blocks to functions to increase readability and reduce duplication. For example you have `SELECT * FROM vids WHERE vidKey = ?` twice, which amounts to quite a lot of duplication (oddly, you one use `s` and once `i`). A function like `getVideoByKey` might be helpful here.

Comment: In .htaccess there's a script that strips tags from all GET and POST tags. I will work on the second part, thank you.

Comment: @Chipperyman filtering tags is not enough against XSS, as the user input is echoed inside script tags.